# Calling to staticmethod from class __init__() causing "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" TypeError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, static-methods

I created a Class with a staticmethod:

```
class DetfileDetector(Detector):
    def __init__(self, file_path, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.detections = self.parse_detfile(file_path)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_detfile(file_path):
        #do somthing with file_path
```

When I call `parse_defile` without instancing the class I get the expected result

```
DetfileDetector.parse_detfile('foo.txt')
```

However, when I call it from **init**() function I get the error:

> TypeError: parse_detfile() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were
> given

I assume that the meaning is that 'self' is also passed to the staticmethod, but this is a staticmethod therefore I expected that self will not be transferred.

My attempts to fix were to set 'file_path' as an optional argument with None as default but I got a TypeEroor of

> TypeError: parse_detfile() got multiple values for argument 'file_path'

I Will appreciate if someone can tell me how to write it the right way.

Edit: thank you for your answers, adding more information:

- I see now that it fails when I run it from 'python interactive shell' of VScode (version 1.50.0-insider), but passes from when running it from command line or without the interactive shell. I shall report this issue to VScode developers.
- I'm using python 3.7.7

Edit2: the content of `Detector` class

```
class Detector:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.every = kwargs.pop('every', 1)
        self.min_confidence = kwargs.pop('min_confidence', .8)
        self.min_wh = kwargs.pop('min_wh', 5)
        self.min_ar = kwargs.pop('min_ar', .1)
        self.sensor_noise_cov = np.square(np.diag(kwargs.pop('sensor_noise', [10, 10, 1, 10])))
        self.classes = object_classes(kwargs.pop('cars_only', True))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. It works as shown in my answer below.

Comment: Can you share the contents of `Detector` class?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I edited the question with `Detector`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is actually **correct**.

I tested it with Python 3.8 and didn't see any problem.

You can call a staticmethod using the class, or an instance of that class.

See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

It was working like this even in older versions of Python, I checked all the way to Python 2.7.
So there's a bit of a mystery of why you're getting that error.

Maybe give more context on your code?

Comment: That was also my suggestion. The issue is not in the code that is presented here

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel we're on the same page. I'm curious where the issue is coming from.

Comment: I am also wondering. Perhaps something in `Detector` ?

Comment: Thanks, Prayson W. Daniel  and Hocli for  your answers, I edited the question with more information

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is not from the code you showed. Tested on Python 3.6, this works:

```py
class Detector:
    pass

class DetfileDetector(Detector):
    def __init__(self, file_path, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.detections = self.parse_detfile(file_path)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_detfile(file_path):
        #do somthing with file_path
        print(file_path)


DetfileDetector('get.txt')
# get.txt

DetfileDetector.parse_detfile('tex.txt')
# tex.txt
```

In VSCode, add breakpoints on your code at **init** and **parse_detfile** and run your code on debug mode to see the variables.

So check `Detector` and see if the issue is there.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this and it should work

```
class DetfileDetector(Detector):
    def __init__(self, file_path, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.detections = DetfileDetector.parse_detfile(file_path)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_detfile(file_path):
        #do somthing with file_path
```

Comment: Would be better to use `self.detections = self.parse_detfile(file_path)` because it doesn't require hardcoding the name of class into the code (and would not need to be modified should the containing class' name is ever change).

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that the meaning is that 'self' is also passed to the staticmethod, but this is a staticmethod therefore I expected that self will not be transferred.

Correct.

Half the point of a `staticmethod` is that you don't need an instance. However, it is still an *attribute* of the class, not a top-level function, so:

> I Will appreciate if someone can tell me how to write it the right way.

you need to look for it within the class, thus:

```
def __init__(self, file_path, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.detections = DetfileDetector.parse_detfile(file_path)
```

Yes, it's a bit awkward, arguably. But the other half of the point of `staticmethod` is that you actually associate the method with the class this way. If that doesn't seem like a benefit, you might instead consider just making a plain, top-level function, outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, this was caused because I had created two modules that had a class with the same name, and the information of the error made me think that the error was in one of the files, when in reality, it was in the other file. See minimal working example below.

As you can see below, the issue is caused because I call `file1.Foo` and provide a parameter, even though its constructor doesn't accept a single parameter. I was confused because the error mentions `Foo.__init__()`, so I thought this referred to the `Foo` class in `file1.py` or the one in `file2.py`.

**`file1.py`**

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello from file1.py')
```

**`file2.py`**

```py
import file1

class Foo():

    def __init__(self, text):
        pass

    def f1(text):
        return 'Hello from f1 - ' + text

    def f2(self):
        bar = file1.Foo(Foo.f1('a'))

a = Foo()
a.f2()
```

**Results of execution**

```
python file2.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myusername/e/file2.py", line 15, in <module>
    a.f2()
  File "/home/myusername/e/file2.py", line 12, in f2
    bar = file1.Foo(Foo.f1('a'))
TypeError: Foo.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

As you might expect, the issue was simply solved by adding a parameter to the constructor in `file1.py`.

**`file1.py`**

```py
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, text):
        print(f'Hello from file1.py')
```

**`file2.py`**

```py
import file1

class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f1(text):
        return 'Hello from f1 - ' + text

    def f2(self):
        bar = file1.Foo(Foo.f1('a'))

a = Foo()
a.f2()
```

**Results of execution**

```
python file2.py
```

```
Hello from file1.py
```

If you are having the same issue, I'd recommend you take a look at those classes that have the same name as the one mentioned in the error.